# VB6/VBA MSFlexGrid to VB.NET DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, vb6-migration, msflexgrid

Yet again, more fantastic **VB6** to **VB.NET** migration.

Okay sure, this isn't necessarily a "Question" in definition, but it will answer many questions that users will have in the future, and will hopefully answer my questions as well.

I am trying to compile a list of properties and functions within `MSFlexGrid` in VB6/VBA and .NET's `DataGridView` that provide the same or *somewhat* same uses. Not only do I need them, but I am sure there are more who do.

So far this is what I have, and I would like others to feel free to add and edit as you please. I hoping this helps me and others convert old controls into .NET controls with the same functionality as in their old code. If you feel like adding, please enter the relation in the BlockQuote and the definition in its proprietary place:

> ```
> VB6/VBA                          VB.NET
>
> MSFlexGrid.Cols         :::::    DataGridView.ColumnCount
> MSFlexGrid.Col          :::::    ???
> MSFlexGrid.Rows         :::::    DataGridView.RowCount
> MSFlexGrid.Row          :::::    ???
> MSFlexGrid.TextMatrix   :::::    DataGridView.Item(Int32,Int32).Value
> MSFlexGrid.TextArray    :::::    ???
> Add More Here           :::::    Add More Here
> ```

---

**Definitions VB6**:

1. MSFlexGrid.**Cols** = Returns or sets the total number of columns in an **MSFlexGrid**.
2. MSFlexGrid.**Col** = Returns or sets the coordinates of the active cell in an **MSFlexGrid**.
3. MSFlexGrid.**Rows** = Returns or sets the total number of rows in an **MSFlexGrid**.
4. MSFlexGrid.**Row** = Returns or sets the coordinates of the active cell in an **MSFlexGrid**.
5. MSFlexGrid.**TextMatrix** = Returns or sets the text contents of an arbitrary cell. This property allows you to set or retrieve the contents of a cell without changing the **Row** and **Col** properties
6. MSFlexGrid.**TextArray** = Returns or sets the text content of an arbitrary cell. This property allows you to set or retrieve the contents of a cell without changing the **Row** and **Col** properties.
7. **Add More Here**

---

**Definitions VB.NET:**

1. DataGridView.**ColumnCount** = Gets or sets the number of columns displayed in the **DataGridView**.
2. DataGridView.**RowCount** = Gets or sets the number of rows displayed in the **DataGridView**.
3. DataGridView.**Item(Int32,Int32).Value** = Provides an indexer to get or set the cell located at the intersection of the column and row with the specified indexes, and then returns the value.
4. **Add More Here**

Comment: In .Net, winform controls (DataGridViews especially) are usually bound to datasources - business objects and Models with DSLs. Where as in VB6 MSFlexGrids were usually populated by hand, or with a ADODB.recordset or the odd occassion where you might bind a HeiracrchicalMSFlexGrid with a Shaped SQL command. So when it comes to MSFlexGrid.Col/Row properties you access to them via your object model rather than the control. Seperation of concerns. *ps edits lol*

Answer (score 1):

For Row and Col properties you could use something like:

```
    Public Class MyGrid
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
(...)
    Public Property Col() As Integer
        Get
                Return Me.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                    Me.CurrentCell = Me(value, Me.CurrentCell.RowIndex)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
(...)
    Public Property Row() As Integer
        Get
                Return Me.CurrentCell.RowIndex
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                    Me.CurrentCell = Me(value, Me.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
(...)
End Class
```

Then keep looking and matching every property, method and events with the original control.